# Programmatically changing the up-next video on Youtube

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-api, polymer

I am writing a browser extension that would allow me to manipulate what video will be played next on Youtube. However, I'm having a hard time finding out what data I need to modify to update the next video.

I've tried to look at the "add to queue" buttons, since they modify what video plays next. However, due to lack of experience with chrome dev tools I can't track down what events they trigger that will change the up-next state.

I'm at a bit of a loss on what to do next other than bruteforce translating YouTube's minified javascript code into a readable format until I find the necessary functions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why don't you grab the video URL and put it inside your local storage when youtube go for reloading the next video you can block that request and load your URL as the next video.

   ```
                                    **or**
   ```
2. Use Chrome Network Inspector to see the request made by youtube when the user hit the Add to queue button.

Comment: For 1 I'd like to be able to be able to change the "up-next" screen as well at the end of the video. For 2, there is no relevant network request being made since this just changes client-side state.